# How to solve Raspberry Pi 3B & Bme280 Remote I/O error

Tags: pi-3, python, i2c

[image]Let me start off with the components used:

```
GPIO extension board to connect the raspberry pi to components
Bme280 (Purple thingy)
Pi 3B
```

Problem description:

This problem was intermittent at first. We were receiving reading and the error occured out of nowhere, made adjustment to the sensor(taking out and putting it back in) which solved it but when we touch the sensor the error showed up again.

We decided to change the sensor and the problem turned from intermittent to persistent. Now we have this as permanent issue.

We removed the package for BME280 and SmBus2 and decided to reinstall it again.

RPI Bme280: https://pypi.org/project/RPi.bme280/

I followed this BME280 installation guide, however when prompting for 'i2cdetect -y 1' there were lines but no number showing up.

What has been confirmed so far:

```
Patching up of circuits was fine, tested with my lecturer pi and it
works fine.

Codes is fine, we even use the sample code provided by RPi.bme280

I2c was enabled everytime
```

Please help me because I am really lost. I needa submit this by next week so any help is appreciated.[image: Picture of the problem]

Comment: This fault is generally caused by poor or loose connections.  We need CLEAR photos showing the connections between the Pi and the device.

Comment: could be the length of the connection too

Comment: length of the connection as in?

Comment: It's **never** going to work until you solder that set of header pins into your BME280 breakout board.

Comment: The header pins is attached to the bme280 sensor